# How to find the mean of numbers spread across multiple servers?

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I have a situation where we have multiple distributed servers holding large data sets in log files. I need to compute the mean (average) of a value, but the data is too big to bring all the data to one server and compute the mean there. How do I compute the mean when the data is across all these servers?

One way I was thinking of was to have each server compute (1) the sum of its own values and (2) the count of how many values there are. This information could be retrieved at one server, and then I could compute the mean as:

`mean = sum(sum values) / sum(count values)`

However, I might have overflow. I guess I could use Java's BigDecimal class to handle all summed values?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about a weighted average of the two means?

Comment: To avoid the overflow... you can divide each number by how many values there are. In fact for `n` values `a1` to `an` you can add `a1/n + a2/n + ... + an/n`

Comment: i was passed Data mining course , our teacher told us for calculating mean for huge amount of numbers , we just need to have a variable `count` and a mean , for every new element we must update the mean in this way : `mean =  ((mean*count)+element)/(++count)`

Comment: if we have weighted mean , then we must update `count` in this way : `count += weight`

Comment: Overflow doesn't become more of a problem just because the data is distributed. If these numbers are floating-point, overflow is extremely unlikely to be a problem. Precision loss could be a problem for very large data sets, but [more stable summation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) can handle that.

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, I initially wrote about integers and thought about overflow. Then I realized the numbers could be floating-point. The core concern is that the sum of the values could be too big when you add them up.

Answer (score 0):

There are variety of solutions along the lines of what you suggested. Instead of transferring the sum and the count maybe you can send the local-mean and the count.

Java's BigDecimal should be adequate for most use-cases.